# How to highlight a String in Django Template

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, highlight

I am writing a django template for my code. The code's output is a runlog of 100s of lines, and all lines start with a time stamp.
How can I write a template that highlights in red all lines that contain the string "host to"? 
thanks!!

view is:

```
def runlog(request):

     path = request.GET.get('FolderPath')
     chapter_number = request.GET.get('chapter_number')

     content = {'chapter_number': chapter_number}

     title = 'Runlog'
     content = Test(content, path)

return render_to_response('myproject/src/sourcefile.html', {'content': content, 'title': title}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The output is:

```
13:46:20: open file file1.TXT
13:46:20: file: run 1
13:46:20: host to A: Deactivate 0
13:46:22: host to A: 0 24 -1 0 0 
13:46:22: A to host: Return=0
##################################
```

Comment: This is a very broad question. You can either write a custom template filter or write some client side (JavaScript) code.

Comment: Thanks! I think i will have to go with custom templates

Comment: What does `Test(content, path)` return?

Comment: Also, add the template code, not the code that renders the template.

Comment: Test(content, path) returns a runlog of hundreds of lines.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. What does it **return**? A list? a tuple? A list of dictionaries? what does it return?

Comment: Ohh.. It returns a cStringIO.StringIO

Comment: Please post whatever `Test` is

Comment: Sorry, but you're killing me :) *Please* post the code that comprises `Test`

Answer (score 2):

Pseduo code, adjust as necessary, but you can use the `in` operator to check for the presence of a string:

```
<table>
    {% for line in lines %}
    <tr>
        <td class="{% if 'host to' in line.contents %}highlighted{% endif %}"></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator for more information.

If you're returning the contents of a file using:

```
#sample.txt

13:46:20: open file file1.TXT
13:46:20: file: run 1
13:46:20: host to A: Deactivate 0
13:46:22: host to A: 0 24 -1 0 0 
13:46:22: A to host: Return=0

file = open('path/to/sample.txt')
contents = file.readlines()
```

You're going to get a list item for each line:

```
>>> print contents
>>> ['13:46:20: open file file1.TXT\n', '13:46:20: file: run 1\n',
    '13:46:20: host to A: Deactivate 0\n',
    '13:46:22: host to A: 0 24 -1 0 0\n', '13:46:22: A to host: Return=0\n']
```

which you can clean up a bit:

```
contents = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in contents]
```

Then you can iterate over that in your Django template:

```
<ul>
{% for line in contents %}
    <li class="{% if 'host to' in line %}highlighted{% endif %}">{{ line }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks! I had already tried something similar, but for some reason nothing is highlighted.

Comment: Yes, @bush please post the view that returns the data, and the template code you've already tried.

Comment: The template code I used was the same as @Brandon but the for loop was different:  {% for string in lines %} , maybe it was a wrong approach